# I want to retrieve unique data from multiple tables also i want to display its table name with records

Tags: mysql

This is my query for getting unique values from 3 tables

```
mysql> SELECT DISTINCT * FROM  (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM TEMP UNION  SELECT DISTINCT * FROM TEMP2 UNION  SELECT DISTINCT * FROM TEMP3)t;
+---------+-------------+-----------------------+
| FNAME   | LNAME       | EMAIL                 |
+---------+-------------+-----------------------+
| Aamir   |  khan       |  xyz@gmail.com        |
| Faiyaz  |  Ahmed      |  abc@gmail.com        |
| Shakeeb |  Uddin      |  pqr@gmail.com        |
| siri    | hema        |  sirihema@aptroid.com |
| sravani |  mettupalle |  sra@aptroid.com      |
| Faiyaz  |  Ahmed      |  abc@yahoo.com        |
+---------+-------------+-----------------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now i also want to display its table name with the retrived records to which it belongs.
please help me out with the optimal query for retrieving unique values from multiple table and also the above asked query. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use a computed column:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM
(
    SELECT FNAME, LNAME, EMAIL, 'TEMP' AS table_source UNION
    SELECT FNAME, LNAME, EMAIL, 'TEMP2'                UNION
    SELECT FNAME, LNAME, EMAIL, 'TEMP3'
) t;
```

The reason this trick works is because we "know" the name of the table in each union query at the moment we select from it.

Comment: load data local infile 'path of file' into [table name] fields separated by ',' set [colomn name] ="your table name';

Comment: I don't understand your comment.

Comment: This is the query i have used for getting unique data as well as for loading a file into a table and for getting the data with its respective table name to which it belongs.